# Mysql table view datatype

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to change the data type bigint(37) to int(11) here. I've tried several methods CAST or CONVERT but ended unsuccessfully.

How can I change the datatype here in this table VIEW? please. thanks.

[image]

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW gtemp_view AS
    SELECT
    d1.Week AS Week1,
    d2.Week AS Week2,
    IF( ABS(d1.dt1-d2.dt1)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt1-d2.dt2)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt1-d2.dt3)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt1-d2.dt4)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt2-d2.dt1)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt2-d2.dt2)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt2-d2.dt3)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt2-d2.dt4)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt3-d2.dt1)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt3-d2.dt2)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt3-d2.dt3)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt3-d2.dt4)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt4-d2.dt1)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt4-d2.dt2)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt4-d2.dt3)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt4-d2.dt4)=0,1,0) AS mcount
FROM gtemp AS d1 , gtemp AS d2 WHERE d1.Week IS NOT NULL AND d2.Week IS NOT NULL AND d1.Week > d2.Week order by Week1 DESC, Week2 DESC limit 200000;
```

Comment: Why  you want change a data type in a view  .? .  the data type is derived  by the query  column datatype involved  in the column result .. But this is a view  ? or is a table?  .

Comment: My data is not big, but mysql assigns bigint(37) by default. I want to change it because i think it slows the performance.

Comment: Update your question and add  you create view code .. .. anyway this should not produce effect on performance

Comment: add  a proper data sample for d1.dt1-d2.dt1 ? ..  could be you code   ..produce (incorrecly) a INT37  .. column

Comment: My data are mostly double digit numbers only, the formula takes difference and adds them.

Comment: i have already posted  an answer  hope is clear ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want see  INT37 in view schema you could try using an explict cast  as unsigned

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW gtemp_view AS
    SELECT
    d1.Week AS Week1,
    d2.Week AS Week2,
    cast( 
    (IF( ABS(d1.dt1-d2.dt1)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt1-d2.dt2)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt1-d2.dt3)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt1-d2.dt4)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt2-d2.dt1)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt2-d2.dt2)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt2-d2.dt3)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt2-d2.dt4)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt3-d2.dt1)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt3-d2.dt2)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt3-d2.dt3)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt3-d2.dt4)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt4-d2.dt1)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt4-d2.dt2)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt4-d2.dt3)=0,1,0) +
    IF( ABS(d1.dt4-d2.dt4)=0,1,0)) 
    AS UNIGNED) mcount
FROM gtemp AS d1 , gtemp AS d2 
WHERE d1.Week IS NOT NULL 
AND d2.Week IS NOT NULL 
AND d1.Week > d2.Week 
order by Week1 DESC, Week2 DESC limit 200000;
```

anyway the cast should impact on performance in  several way  ..instead  the INT37 datatype don't should produce appretiable performance degrade

Comment: I tried it, now it's become bigint(21). is there a way to assign INT in the query? I guess I can't change it after creating the view.

Comment: .. the cast for unsigned can't produce a lower datatype .. and there is not other cast ..  .. but .. i repeat .. the type of INT declared  don't produce effetc on performance  .. the numerica datatyppe are store fixed  number of bytes  ..  for unisgned is 64 bit  .. (4bytes) .. and this for the recent version of mysql is the minum space allocated for integer

Comment: ok. thanks for your time and help really. I'll use your solution.